# ON CONFLICT IGNORE - How to insert data into a dupes table if there is a conflict instead of ignoring

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers, constraints, conflict

I have this query:

```
 @db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS programs(programId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL 
     AUTOINCREMENT, programName TEXT NOT NULL, episodeName TEXT, UNIQUE(programName, 
     episodeName) ON CONFLICT IGNORE)")
```

Instead of ignoring this, what I'd like it to do is to insert the the data into a "Conflicts" table if there is a conflict in any one of my tables. How do I set up for this scenario? Obviously Id have to have the conflicts table created but what next?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE programs
(
  programId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
  programName TEXT NOT NULL, 
  episodeName TEXT, 
  UNIQUE(programName, episodeName) ON CONFLICT IGNORE
);
CREATE TABLE program_dupes
(
  programId INTEGER, 
  programName TEXT, 
  episodeName TEXT 
);
```

Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_programs_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON programs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO program_dupes (programId, programName, episodeName)
  SELECT programId, NEW.programName, NEW.episodeName
    FROM programs
   WHERE programName = NEW.programName 
     AND episodeName = NEW.episodeName;

END
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e8c81/1)** demo